# Convert non-linear equation into linear form i.e. (Y=mX+c)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How would you go about converting ${1\over y} = x^2 + a^{b-x} $ into linear form.
I know how you would normally go about solving this type of problem but I fail to make any progress on this one.

I have to make it in the form $Y = mX + c$

where,
 $Y$ and $X$ are in terms of $x$ and $y$ (the variables) without a and b (the constants); m and c are in terms of a and b (the constants) without x and y (the variables).

I'm having trouble separating the $a$ and $x$ in the $a^{b-x} $ term. Thank you, all help is appreciated.

note: I haven't posted any of my working because I wasn't really able to get anywhere.

Comment: Are you looking for a linear *approximation* of this equation ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I was able to solve it, in case anyone was wondering...

${1\over y} = x^2 + a^{b-x}$

${1\over y}- x^2= a^{b-x}$

$\log({{1\over y}- x^2})= \log({a^{b-x}})$

$\log({{1\over y}- x^2})= (b-x)\log({a})$

$\log({{1\over y}- x^2})= -\log({a})\times x + \log{a^b}$

$Y = mX + c$

where $Y = \log({{1\over y}- x^2})$ , $m=-\log({a})$ , $X = x$ and $c=\log{a^b}$

Comment: You cannot have $x$ in the left hand side of your re-arragenment if you're looking for $y=mx+c$.

Comment: @Autolatry: actually, that's part of the correct way to approach this, is to find out if there's an $Y=f(x,y),X=g(x,y)$ that linearize the given equation...

Comment: One piece that is not so apparent to me is that it appears that there are now restrictions on $X,Y$ and $x,y$ in terms of what values each can take on, while the original appears to have full access to $\Bbb R^2$...

Comment: @abiessu not as it was written it's not. I agree with your point though.

Comment: @abiessu: The original motivation was not explained in the question. If you have two measurable variables $x,y$ and have a lot of data points (each point being a pair of simultaneous measurements of $x,y$), and suspect that $x,y$ obey the given equation for some constants $a,b$, then you might like to 'linearize' the equation into a form $Y=mX+c$ that allows you to estimate $m,c$ in the best-fit linear regression and obtain $a,b$ from them. So it does not matter whether the linearized form has more restrictions on $X,Y$, because you are only interested in the data you actually have.